# Why is Google Analytics Admin API telling me I do not have permission?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client, google-analytics-4

I am accessing the Google Analytics Admin API via the following:

```
import os
from google.analytics.admin import AnalyticsAdminServiceClient

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "service_account_credentials.json"

client = AnalyticsAdminServiceClient()

client.get_account(name='accounts/134494883')
```

I get `PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission error.`

The service account credentials json was downloaded as a key from a service account with full owner permissions. The Google Analytics Admin API, Google Analytics API, and Analytics Reporting API are enabled. I can see that the requests are going through for the analytics admin API but I only get permission errors returned to me. Trying another method such as `client.list_accounts()` returns no error, but a blank list. I am assuming that is why the error rate is only 27%. There are multiple UA and GA4 accounts that exist under this google account.

[image]

Comment: Did you authorize the service account to access your data

Comment: The service account has ownership permissions (the highest possible level I can give it) to all of my google cloud, the exact same as my own user account. That should be sufficient no?

Comment: Did you do it in the google analytics website under the admin section?

Comment: I have hundreds of analytics accounts. If I wanted to get a list of all of the GA accounts in my google account, would I need to add the service account email to each site manually?

Comment: yes or use Oauth2 and authorize the application with your own user